# every category is equivalent to its universal cover

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I am just curious how could we show that every category is equivalent to its universal cover. To me, it is not obvious how could we assign to each an object in a category $\mathcal{C}$ to a family of objects with maps subject to compatibility conditions.

Comment: What is the universal cover of a category?

Comment: A quick search on "universal cover of a category" gives the following definition: the universal cover of (the connected category) $\mathcal C$ based at the point $c$ is the comma category $(c\downarrow \iota)$ where $\iota\colon \mathcal C \to \pi_1(\mathcal C)$ is the inclusion of $\mathcal C$ into its fundamental groupoid. Is it your definition as well? If so, I'm wondering if the stated result is true... (I don't have the time to think further for now though.)

Comment: I used the general definition of " universal cover". It is the one in "Lectures on tensor categories and modular functor". See
http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~kirillov/tensor/tensor.html

Comment: When linking to a 200 page book containing your definition it's helpful to include a more precise reference. I was feeling unusually persistent, and after failing to find the term "universal cover" in the index, I had to run the book through OCR before I could search it. This is Definition 1.1.11, p. 14. The question is how to prove Lemma 1.1.12, which is left to the reader.

Comment: @Dan: I don't know what you mean by "the general definition," but I for one have never seen it before, and I think it's a very strange definition considering that it doesn't restrict to what people usually mean by the universal cover on groupoids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the definition: an object of the "universal cover" $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ of a category $\mathcal C$ is an indiscrete subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$, and a morphism $(A,(\phi_{a,a'})_{a,a' \in A}) \to (B,(\psi_{b,b'})_{b,b' \in B})$ is a collection $(f_{ab})_{a \in A,b \in B}$ of arrows which are natural in the obvious way. Composition is actually not quite trivial in this category -- there are many ways you can compose the $f_{ab}$'s with $g_{bc}$'s, but it turns out they are all equal because of the naturality conditions. Identities are also fun.

Bakalov and Kirilov point out the (obvious) equivalence functor $\mathcal{C} \to \hat{\mathcal{C}}$, sending an object to the singleton set containing that object. All you have to do is show that it is full, faithful and essentially surjective. It's completely obvious that this functor is full and faithful. So all you have to show is that it's essentially surjective.

Actually, there is a mistake in the definition. You need to restrict the objects to be *nonempty* indiscrete subcategories, i.e. we can't allow $A$ above to be empty. If we do allow $A$ to be empty, then composition is not well defined.

Comment: The notation $(A,(\phi_a)_{a\in A})$ is not entirely clear. So, the thing is that all objects of such an indiscrete subcategory $A$ are isomorphic to each other, and hence $A$ can be mapped to any of its object. Cannot an initial object be mapped to the empty subcategory?

Comment: Thanks for the notation point, I've fixed it and now hopefully it's clear that $\phi_{a,a'}$ means the morphism $a \to a'$ in the indiscrete subcategory we're talking about. The issue with allowing empty subcategories is that as I've defined things, you would have unique morphisms $A \to \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \to B$. This is already a red flag because it says that $\hat{\mathcal C}$ has a zero object, even if $\mathcal C$ didn't. Moreover, what should the composition $A \to \emptyset \to B$ be? In fact, for some $A,B$ there aren't even any options unless the category is strongly connected.

Comment: Aha, ok, you convinced me :)

Comment: What about the other functor? I mean how could we assign to each an object $(A,(\phi_{a,a'})_{a,a' \in A}) $ in $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ one object in $\mathcal{C}$ ?

Thanks,

Comment: It does seem strange, doesn't it? I suppose that's because you need to use the axiom of choice in an essential way. I appealed to the theorem which says that a full, faithful, and essentially surjective functor is an equivalence. So it bears thinking through what actually happens in the proof of that theorem.